# Tabbulation in an <input /> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to insert a tabbulation character into an input element?

**The task:** i have **one** input, the user types 6 characters, which must look like: 
 3 characters [empty space] 3 characters. 
**The problem:** the left position of the second 3 characters must not change.

For example:

 
*looks*:
   MMM [ ] OPS
   III [ ] DOS
*must look*:
   MMM [ ] OPS
   III [       ] DOS

*There must be no manipulation with the font-type.*

ty

Comment: I don’t quite get what you’re asking for. Do you want to know how to insert a tabulation character programmatically or how to insert it directly via the keyboard? And what about these three characters you are talking about?

Comment: In addition to Gumbo's questions, why can't you just have 6 characters, read 3 then read 3... or use a single space?

Comment: the characters is my "problem" and inserting a tab is my "solution", but i'm hoping, that some-one here has a better one.

Comment: Shaded: because the characters have different length.

Comment: ohhh I get it now, you're not looking for a tab or anything of the sort. Your problem is your font! There are fonts you can use that has a fixed length. Really your question should be "How can I change the font in my input to fixed length?" and that... I don't know, but I'll look it up :D

Comment: Shaded, that's great, but i wrote at the end: "There must be no manipulation with the font-type" :<

Comment: oh... well then, I don't think there is an easy solution. Because essentially you would need to find out the width of every character in the input and adjust the amount of spaces between accordingly.

Comment: that's what i reeeealy don't want 2 do :<

Comment: @yoz1k - if you don't want to figure out the width of every character and don't want to use a monospace font, then there's absolutely nothing that you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to me why one would have to align the *input* ... but I can think of a number of alternative solutions that may make sense depending on what the actual stated requirements are (i.e. what is the *reason* the input has to be aligned)

You could have a 6 char  field (or 7 and include the space) with a "preview" to the right (or below, whatever) that formats and aligns the two 3-char codes as you type in the input field.

You could have two separate input fields, and use javascript to auto-tab between them as you type (tab right when full) or backspace (tab left when field 2 is empty)

You could also use javascript to automatically insert a tab (\t) in your field after 3 chars are typed, or when a space is typed replace it with a tab.

The approach I'd use depends entirely on what the field(s) and 3-letter codes are and why they're being input at this time. For a fixed set of codes I might use select lists instead of input.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, insert a tab character `"\t"`. You can copy-pasta it from a text editor, or use javascript to detect the tab key and use it to insert a tab char. Be careful how you override default behaviors though, as the tab key is used for accessibility purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\t` character escape within the input value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#text1").val("MMM\tOPS");
    $("#text2").val("III\t\tOPS");
});
```

Note, however, that I had to use one tabulation character in the first text box and two tabulation characters in the second text box in order to properly align the result.

Comment: Just remember that user agents are allowed to display the tab length differently. There is **no** way of specifying that a tab take up a certain length.